# How can I get expandedArchive temporary folder using zipTree method in gradle?

Tags: groovy, gradle

using zipTree method in Gradle I obtain a FileTree that I can use in copy task or for other purpose. But how can I get the temporary extension folder created by the method?

Inspecting fileTree(zipArchive) properties I view this:

```
asFileTrees:[directory 'C:\WS\MarsWS\PlaygroundGradle\build\tmp\expandedArchives\TestTools-1.0.zip_18lgn8937j72gznum7h3vilu9']
```

but I cannot find any method to access that directory path.

Do you know how can I retrieve it?

Thanks,
Michele.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def tmpPath = zipTree(<zip path>).getTree().getMirror().getDir()
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation of what this does to your post?